# I am getting a null value in the foreign key for a OnetoMany and ManytoOne mapping

Tags: hibernate

These are my classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="COURSE")
public class Course {
    @Id
    @Column(name="COURSE_ID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "COURSE_ID_SEQ", sequenceName = "COURSE_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "COURSE_ID_SEQ", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private int courseId;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
            mappedBy = "noteBatch",
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<NoteID> notesIds;
}



@Entity
@Table(name="NOTE_IDS")
public class NoteID {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="note_course_id", nullable = false)
    private Course noteBatch;

    @Id
    @Column(name="note_id")
    private int notesId;
}
```

The problem is that whenever I persist an object of type course, I get a null value for the attribute "note_course_id" in the table NOTE_IDS.

I am using postman for testing. Here is my json object.

```
{
 "notesIds": [{ 
                  "notesId": 8   
              }
             ],
}
```

I don't know if the problem is that I am not setting note_course_id in the json object, so it initializes the field as null on the other side.